# How to revert an area split

Tags: 3d-view

I accidentally used the "Split Area" option by right clicking on the border of my viewport, then tried to join them back together, but just ended up losing my original work! The new window is colorless, but the render still shows my original!

I'm using Cycles, but there are no shadows in the new window, nor any light.
It ruined my few hours of work and it's very irritating.

Comment: Click on the new border with right mouse button and select "Join Area" then move the mouse to the new area and click with the left button.

Comment: I fixed this now, but not your way. I have already joined the areas, but accidentally the other way around, thus losing my first screen. I just had to set the new viewport to the render view (upper right corner of the viewport) and it fixed my issue!